# initializing custom classes and autofac injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

Let's assume I have a class like this

```
 public class Test {
     public IMyService MyService { get; set;}

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I have the service injected with propertiesautowired in Autofac?

How can I run something like this:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.MyService.DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can autowire property for concrete classes in autofac as below

```
builder.RegisterType<Test>().PropertiesAutowired();
```